# How to implement a social media feed

Tags: entities, forms, feeds, social-network

I am creating a social media app and basically need a page that is a form with fields for the users to fill out and add a new post to their feed (form connects to the feed).

More detail:
The form should be able to have an added entity reference to taxonomy terms, allowing users to upload text, image and video, and then select a taxonomy term for the above post to be posted to, basically categorizing posts. For example, a taxonomy term “Covid-19” exists (acting like a category) and a user wants to add a post (text, image, video, likes, comments) specifically about Covid-19. When filling out the form the user selects “covid-19” and submit post, now any user is able to find that new post under the “covid-19” category/taxonomy term.

My setup:

- Drupal 9 with Open Social (distribution)
- MAMP stack (LAMP on Mac) with DDEV

I’m still pretty new to Drupal so I apologize but here’s what I’ve tried so far:

- Setup taxonomy terms/ categories
- Created home page with a posts feed and added a filter on the page’s view to filter by taxonomy terms
- Created post page (as a dynamic page content type) with a single field that’s a reference to the taxonomy terms

What I thought would’ve worked:

- Adding fields to the content type but I couldn’t find any sort of form field (and the media field isn’t letting me add media/ what I’m calling a post)
- Adding fields to the pages view, but I got the same result

At this point I believe I just need to add those fields if I’m not wrong.

- How can I add/connect the form?
- And is the “media” field not the solution I need for what I’m calling a post (username, text, image, video, likes and comments)?
- If media is the solution but without the upload/ add video option, would the solution for adding video (or forms) be in another module? Or is the full solution already a module? (Keep in mind I’m already on the Open Social distribution if applicable)

Sorry again for the beginner question, I tried being as helpful as I could. Any help at all is GREATLY appreciated, thank you to anyone who reads this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a way for users to post content and organize that content by taxonomy terms, a content type is the way to go.

You don't attach a form to a content type; in Drupal, the content type IS the form.

Since you've already created the content type and added a taxonomy reference field for tags/categories, you can add the other fields.

Make sure you're adding the fields under `Admin -> Structure -> Content Types -> My Content Type -> Manage Fields`.

You said you want to add a username, text, image, video, likes and comments.

- Username: You don't need a field for this because Drupal already has the username because the user is logged in to post.  (Unless you allow anonymous users to post, but I'll keep this short.)
- Text: You can add a standard textarea (Text (plain, long)).
- Image: There are several ways to do this, but in your case, to attach images to posts, I would tentatively recommend adding an Image reference.  You should research this.
- Video: This can be a media reference to a video field.  You'll need to make sure you have media enabled for video.
- Likes: Not sure how you would implement this; it's certainly possible but it's not supported in Drupal out of the box.
- Comments: Enable comments module and read the docs on how to set it up for your content type.  But, Drupals comments are a little neglected and primitive compared to a lot of social media, so if you expect heavy commenting, you might look at a third-party solution too.

As you may have guessed, the scope of your question is way too broad for this site, so I couldn't give too many specific details, but hopefully these pointers show you the way to go about this.

Comment: You are the best thank you very much! Unfortunately I’m also new to this site as well but if I can help ur score on it or something let me know, I’m unable to vote on your comment :(

Comment: @Pleasehelpme You're welcome.  You can check the checkmark below the voting widget to accept the answer.  You can upvote (when you get the privilege) as many questions and answers as you want, but you can only accept one answer to each question you ask.